How to install a specific nextjs version?
I'm trying to install nextjs version 12.1.0 but I keep getting nextjs 15.
I tried: npx create-next-app@12 and got nothing.
Also tried: npx create-next-app@12 app-name && cd my-app && npm i next@12
The cli does not pick up the & sign

Since npx create-next-app@12 app-name might still download the newest version of Next, you should try the following:
npm install next@12.1.0
npx create-next-app app-name

In package.json, make sure the Next version is 12.1.0, otherwise change it manually ("next": "12.1.0") and run
npm install

to install the dependencies again with this version.
Tell me if it works for you!
